# how can I make a nested table with many foreach

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

I need to make a report with pure tours but as you can see in excel but it does not work for me I would like It to look like this
[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIz3F.png)

but this is what I end up with

[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkgK.png)

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Verificador</th>
            <th scope="col">ETAPA</th>
            <th scope="col">ACTIVIDAD GENERAL</th>
            <th scope="col">ACTIVIDAD</th>
            <th scope="col">PRODUCTO A ENTREGAR</th>
            <th scope="col">EVIDENCIA</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($project->administrators as $administrator)
                <td>  {{$administrator->name}}</td>
                @foreach($project->phases as $phase)            
                    <td>{{$phase->name}}</td>

                    @foreach ($phase->activities as $activity)

                        @if ($activity->parent_id==null)

                            <td><p style="background: red;" >{{$activity->name}}</p></td>
                        @endif

                        @foreach($activity->activities as $especifics)
                                <td>{{$especifics->name}}</td>  
                            @foreach($especifics->products as $product)
                                 <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                                @foreach($product->productdetails as $productdetail)
                                <td>{{$productdetail->name}}</td>
                                    @foreach($productdetail->evidence as $evidence )
                                    <td>{{$evidence->path}}</td>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach    
                            @endforeach 
                        @endforeach    
                    @endforeach 
                @endforeach 

            @endforeach 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pro Tip: If your question does not come with a code example, it is _probably_ not On Topic for StackOverflow

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm modifying why it does not appear

Comment: @WilmerRamiroCristanchoCruz it may help to mention that you're using Laravel in your question. Also, have you considered using the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes instead of nested tables?

Comment: The image for which you have stated that the report should look like has not been added. please edit to make the question clear

Comment: if I used colspan in rowspan but I fail to go through the data and it looks that way

Comment: I have two photos one as I have it and another as it should be

Comment: You can make the links into photos by adding a `!` before the `[text here]`. Please look at [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) for more info

Comment: Instead of nesting loops until you're indented into your neighbour's house why not put a method in each object that defines how to dfisplay itself, and calls the same method on its children?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hope this will help you achieve what you really desire for but I have just done it in HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>table in table
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th>4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>In head 1</td>
        <td>In head 2</td>
        <td>in head 3</td>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <td>In head 4.1</td>
                <td>In head 4.2</td>
                <td>In head 4.3</td>
                <td>In head 4.4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>44</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: If I had seen that and I thank you, but when there is a lot of data to generate the report, all these data are being dismantled.

Answer (score -1):

Doing some research online will help you solve your problem please go through this to get a solution
https://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/nestingtables.html

Netsing of tables in a serverside language requires knowledge of the basic html for example if I can use your code, I'd propose you editikng it like this

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Verificador</th>
        <th scope="col">ETAPA</th>
        <th scope="col">ACTIVIDAD GENERAL</th>
        <th scope="col">ACTIVIDAD</th>
        <th scope="col">PRODUCTO A ENTREGAR</th>
        <th scope="col">EVIDENCIA</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($project->administrators as $administrator)
            <td> 
          //you may want to have the second table inside the first table here
                 <table>
                   <tr><td> {{$administrator->name}}</td>
            @foreach($project->phases as $phase)            
                <td>{{$phase->name}}</td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>            
             //close the second table

                @foreach ($phase->activities as $activity)

                    @if ($activity->parent_id==null)

                        <td><p style="background: red;" >{{$activity->name}}</p></td>
                    @endif

                    @foreach($activity->activities as $especifics)
                            <td>{{$especifics->name}}</td>  
                        @foreach($especifics->products as $product)
                             <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                            @foreach($product->productdetails as $productdetail)
                            <td>{{$productdetail->name}}</td>
                                @foreach($productdetail->evidence as $evidence )
                                <td>{{$evidence->path}}</td>
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach    
                        @endforeach 
                    @endforeach    
                @endforeach 
            @endforeach 

        @endforeach 
    </tbody>
```

I have only added one table as I am struggling to get you other data being passed but as you can see nesting mainly requuires one to know whatv is to be put insite wgat like in you case you need to know

1. what table is to contains what
2. What will be the parent table for what etc

Comment: This is a helpful reference on nesting tables, would you care to expand your answer so it has the main gist of the reference without having to visit the link? Also, I believe OP 's asking more about how to implement this in PHP rather than how to nest HTML tables.